# MS Office Communicator: Long delays in setting up audio connection when starting a call

Tags: ms-office-communicator

I am using Microsoft Office Communicator with a USB headset as my work phone. OCS is connected to our PABX so we can take and make calls to regular, non-OCS phones. When making an external call to a cellphone, it can take up to 5-10 seconds for audio to start flowing.

eg:

```
Work Phone                  Cellphone
- dial cellphone
  (ringing)                 (ringing)
                            answer cellphone
  (hearing nothing)         speak "1"
   .                        speak "2"
   .                        speak "3"
   .                        ...
   .                        speak "14"
  hear "15"                 speak "15"
  hear "16"                 speak "16"
```

Has anyone experienced this kind of thing with an OCS setup? Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be really interested to know what happens when you run the OCS pre-call diagnostic tool (http://blogs.technet.com/brettjo/archive/2009/09/20/ocs-pre-call-diagnostic-tool.aspx) before placing a call. This sounds to me like you're having a latency problem.